# Why is while not an expression in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust. It seems to me that a major difference between `loop` and `while` is that `loop` is an expression that returns a value. But why can't `while` be an expression? Code like this won't compile:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut count = 0;
    let x = while count != 2 {
        count += 1;
        count
    };
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

But maybe the compiler could interpret the `while` block like this:

```rust
let x = {
    count += 1; // 1st iteration
    count += 1; // 2nd iteration
    count
};
```

I know this looks semanticly strange. But is this the only reason that `loop` exist?

I'm aware that `while true` is not allowd, but you can always do this

```rust
let x = 10;
while x != 11 {
    println!("test");
}
```

which behaves exactly like `while true`.

Comment: loop is here to express an unconditional loop. loop that return a value was not the first version of loop. while is often if not always use for side effect so it's natural for while to not return a value

Comment: There is no guarantee that the compiler will know how many times the while loop will run. While loops can easily become more complicated than the example used. The while loop could call a function. Or the value of "count" could be retrieved from a file, user input, or a function that's not guaranteed to return the same value each time it's called. In such a scenario, the compiler cannot know how many times the loop will run.

Comment: @taotsi a `loop` always runs at least once even if it's immediately broken out of, as such the `break` used to exit can always generate a value. A `while` may execute the body 0 times (if the condition is immediately false, likewise a `for` with an empty iterator), therefore there are situations where it has no way to generate a return value, unless the syntax is extended somehow to handle this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But why can't while be an expression?

There have been many discussions about this and at least one RFC. There are many details to resolve. For instance, what do you do when a `while` does not enter the body the first time?

> But is this the only reason that loop exist?

It was the most reasonable one to have first. `loop` was not always an expression either!

> I'm aware that while true is not allowd

It is allowed although the relevant warning is enabled by default.